# AccessException: composer network ping does not generate certificates

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to issue a new identity to a participant, create a `composer card` and import it.

My base.cto file is

```
namespace com.algorythmix.base

participant Department identified by departmentId {
  o String departmentId
}
```

My function to issue an identity

```
const initIdentities = () => {
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      const businessNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
      await businessNetworkConnection.connect(adminCardName);
      let departmentRegistry =  await businessNetworkConnection.getParticipantRegistry(`${BASE_NS}.Department`);
      let departmentOne = await departmentRegistry.get('departmentOne');
      let deptOne = await businessNetworkConnection.issueIdentity(`${BASE_NS}.Department#${departmentOne.departmentId}`, 'departmentOne');
      console.log(`userID = ${deptOne.userID}`);
      console.log(`userSecret = ${deptOne.userSecret}`);

      let departmentTwo = await departmentRegistry.get('departmentTwo');
      let deptTwo = await businessNetworkConnection.issueIdentity(`${BASE_NS}.Department#${departmentTwo.departmentId}`, 'departmentTwo');
      console.log(`userID = ${deptTwo.userID}`);
      console.log(`userSecret = ${deptTwo.userSecret}`);

      const adminConnection = new AdminConnection(); // { cardStore: $SOME_PATH_VARIABLE } to change def2ault card storage path
      await adminConnection.connect(adminCardName); // Confirm this
      console.log('connected');
      const cardOne = new IdCard({
        userName: 'departmentOne',
        version: 1,
        enrollmentSecret: deptOne.userSecret,
        businessNetwork: 'chips'
      }, connectionProfile);
      const cardTwo = new IdCard({
        userName: 'departmentTwo',
        version: 1,
        enrollmentSecret: deptTwo.userSecret,
        businessNetwork: 'chips'
      }, connectionProfile);
      console.log('importing card one');
      await adminConnection.importCard('departmentOne', cardOne);
      await adminConnection.importCard('departmentTwo', cardTwo);
      console.log('imported card two');
      await businessNetworkConnection.disconnect();
      await adminConnection.disconnect();
      resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    };
  });
};
```

Where `adminCardName` is the one generated when using `composer network start` command as per the basic tutorial provided here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org
And `connectionProfile` is taken from the above page as well. I have double checked the connection profile used by the `admin@chips` card and the one I have used is exactly the same.

Once I run the function, in `composer card list`, a card called `departmentOne` and `departmentTwo` is listed with the Business network shown as `chips` (as expected).

Now when I run `composer network ping -c departmentOne`, I get the error

```
Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: AccessException: Participant 'com.algorythmix.base.Department#departmentOne' does not have 'READ' access to resource 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#chips@0.2.0'
Command failed
```

I have
1) Deleted `permissions.acl` which as per the documentation results in everyone getting full access
2) used following `permissions.acl` file

```
rule Default {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant: "com.algorythmix.base.Department"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

To specifically give the participant access to the network. I have also uploaded the `.bna` to `composer-playground` and it works over there as expected.

Can someone please guide me, as to what I am doing wrong?
Info:
Ubuntu - 16.0.4
Fabric - 1.1
Composer - 0.19.11
Node - 8.9.1

Answer (score 1):

the error `'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#chips@0.2.0'` suggests the underlying participant does not have the minimal READ access to the actual business network.

I would suggest a rule (rule 2) something like this:

```
rule ReadNetwork {
    description: "Allow all participants to read network"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
    action: ALLOW
}
```

Comment: I did add this and it still did not work. However I changed the version in `package.json` to 1.0.0 and it worked. I then changed the version back to 0.2.0 and it threw this error. So I got it working, but have no clue why it works. I even tried changing the resource to 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#chips@0.2.0' in the acl you showed above

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by changing the version in package.json file.